# CodecConfigurationException when updating list of objects in document

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am currently experiencing a CodecConfigurationException with a particular entity. I've tried adding a custom codec for the object in question but that didn't appear to resolve the issue. The error message is:

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfiguration: Can't find a codec for class net.fancycow.common.ecs.entities.FancyBox

What I find odd is that PlayerData has a list of another custom class (which I've omitted from the code) called Unlock and it's never complained about class codecs, but for some reason or another it does so for FancyBox. The Component class as seen in the Entity class is just an interface that my various components implement, so FancyBox will have various different component types. If anyone can point me in the right direction as to how I can resolve this issue I would really appreciate it as I've yet to come across a solution for this that has worked for my case.

PlayerData.class

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(value = "players", noClassnameStored = true)
public class PlayerData {
    @Id
    @Getter
    private String uuid;

    @Getter
    private List<FancyBox> fancyBoxes = Lists.newArrayList();

    public PlayerData(UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid.toString();
    }
}
```

FancyBox.class

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FancyBox extends Entity {
    /**
     * Minimum quality of fancy boxes.
     */
    public static final int MIN_QUALITY = 1;
    /**
     * Maximum quality of fancy boxes.
     */
    public static final int MAX_QUALITY = 5;
    /**
     * Rarity count mapping for each quality.
     */
    public static final Multimap<Integer, Entry<Rarity, Integer>> QUALITY_GENERATION = ArrayListMultimap.create();

    static {
        QUALITY_GENERATION.putAll(1, Lists.newArrayList(new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.COMMON, 3),
                new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.UNCOMMON, 2),
                new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.RARE, 1)));
        QUALITY_GENERATION.putAll(2, Lists.newArrayList(new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.COMMON, 2),
                new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.UNCOMMON, 2),
                new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.RARE, 1),
                new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.EPIC, 1)));
        QUALITY_GENERATION.putAll(3, Lists.newArrayList(new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.UNCOMMON, 2),
                new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.RARE, 2),
                new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.EPIC, 1),
                new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.LEGENDARY, 1)));
        QUALITY_GENERATION.putAll(4, Lists.newArrayList(new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.RARE, 2),
                new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.EPIC, 2),
                new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.LEGENDARY, 1),
                new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.SUPREME, 1)));
        QUALITY_GENERATION.putAll(1, Lists.newArrayList(new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.EPIC, 3),
                new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.LEGENDARY, 2),
                new SimpleEntry<>(Rarity.SUPREME, 1)));
    }

    public FancyBox(@NonNull FancyBoxType type, int quality) {
        addComponent(new FancyBoxTypeComponent(type));
        addComponent(new QualityComponent(quality, MAX_QUALITY));
        addComponent(new DateCreationComponent());
    }
}
```

Entity.class

```
public class Entity {
    protected List<Component> components = Lists.newArrayList();

    public Entity addComponent(@NonNull Component component) {
        if (!hasComponent(component.getClass()))
            this.components.add(component);
        return this;
    }

    public Entity removeComponent(@NonNull Component component) {
        this.components.remove(component);
        return this;
    }

    public Entity removeComponent(@NonNull Class<? extends Component> type) {
        Lists.newArrayList(this.components).stream()
                .filter(component -> component.getClass() == type)
                .forEach(component -> this.components.remove(component));
        return this;
    }

    public <T extends Component> T getComponent(@NonNull Class<T> type) {
        return (T) this.components.stream()
                .filter(component -> type.isAssignableFrom(component.getClass()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }

    public boolean hasComponent(@NonNull Class<?> type) {
        return this.components.stream()
                .filter(component -> component.getClass().equals(type))
                .count() > 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after further testing and research I discovered that it was an issue with UpdateOperations#addAll in Morphia 1.2.x. I updated to Morphia 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT and switched to UpdateOperation#push and everything works great now.